# open custom authentication module access http session

Tags: authentication, openam

How can i access http session and request/response from openam custom authentication module? Any one has idea?

I am trying openam sample auth module, but no where i found a way to access httpservletrequest etc.

I have a requirement to access httpsession as i am working on challenge/signature authentication. I store the challenge in session on Login.jsp and client signs it. Now inside custom auth module, i need access to that challenge in session to verify.

Is it passed somewhere in init
 public void init(Subject subject, Map sharedState, Map options)

Answer (score 0):

Every custom auth module extends from AMLoginModule which has HttpServletReequest :)